# Sort records in random order for specific group of data using MySQL select query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

I have a below db table structure :

```
Tablename : agency_mst
Fields:
id
name
is_premium
date_added
```

I want to sort the data so that the agencies with **is_premium=1** comes first and the rest of the data is sorted by **date_added desc** order.

But also the is_premium=1 records should be sorted in **random order**. so first set of premium agencies will have random order. How can I do that using MySQL Select query.

I have built this query partially but not sure how to filter specific set of data. Below is that query:

```
SELECT * FROM agency_mst
ORDER BY is_premium DESC, date_added DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
SELECT * 
  FROM agency_mst
 ORDER BY IF(is_premium=1, RAND(), -1.0), date_added DESC
```

That will use random ordering for the matching rows, then put the others last, and order them by date.

Be careful with performance, though. `ORDER BY RAND()` in any variant is a notorious performance antipattern in tables with many rows.

Comment: Thanks, just tried this but when there is just one agency with is_premium=1 then its not coming on top.

Comment: A Slight modification to your query fixed this

IF(is_premium=1, RAND(), -1.0) DESC,

Thank You :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.id,t1.name,t1.is_premium,t1.date_added from 
(select (ROW_NUMBER() over (order by id))* cast(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(10) as int) RND,* from agency_mst) t1
order by t1.RND
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, name, is_premium , date_added ,if(is_premium ,rand()*-15,0) as first_order
 FROM agency_mst
ORDER BY first_order, date_added DESC
```

Check This Using rand()*-15 you get -velue it show first and remain will be 0 and that will be order by date_added